# How to pick the element using given screen coordinates - selenium, java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webautomation

I need to know what is the element loaded to the given screen coordinates.
There are dynamic elements loaded in my web page's specific location (top left of the screen).
So I need to know what is the element loaded in the given screen area. (please refer below pic)
And log the time and element details.

[image]

I'm using selenium and java and can use 'JavascriptExecutor' if needed.
So any idea how to get these elements by screen coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
package selenium;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class CoordinateTest extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         // wrapped driver init
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        
        // get screen resolution
        Dimension screenDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenWidth = (int) screenDimension.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = (int) screenDimension.getHeight();

        // desired rectangle
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200, 0, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 10);
        
        List<WebElement> rElements = getElementsFromRectangle(driver, r);
        for (WebElement element: rElements) {
            System.out.println("tag: " + element.getTagName());
            System.out.println("location: " + element.getLocation());
            System.out.println("text: " + element.getText() + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static List<WebElement> getElementsFromRectangle(WebDriver driver, Rectangle r) {
        List<WebElement> rElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
        for (WebElement element: allElements) {
            if (elementIsInsideRectangle(element, r)) {
                rElements.add(element);
            }
        }
        return rElements;
    }
    
    public static Boolean elementIsInsideRectangle(WebElement element, Rectangle r) {
        int x = element.getRect().getX();
        int y = element.getRect().getY();
        int w = element.getRect().getWidth();
        int h = element.getRect().getHeight();
        int rMinX = (int) r.getMinX();
        int rMaxX = (int) r.getMaxX();
        int rMinY = (int) r.getMinY();
        int rMaxY = (int) r.getMaxY();
        if (x >= rMinX && x <= rMaxX && y >= rMinY && y <= rMaxY && x + h <= rMinX + rMaxX && y + w <= rMinY + rMaxY) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 29403
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 16, 2021 2:50:59 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
tag: a
location: (319, 3)
text: 

tag: span
location: (332, 25)
text: 

tag: li
location: (531, 12)
text: About

tag: a
location: (531, 12)
text: About

tag: li
location: (602, 12)
text: Products

tag: a
location: (602, 12)
text: Products

tag: li
location: (689, 12)
text: For Teams

tag: a
location: (689, 12)
text: For Teams

tag: svg
location: (802, 17)
text: 

tag: path
location: (802, 17)
text:
```